# Remote system development of C/C++ in Eclipse|Netbeans

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, netbeans

I am trying to use Eclipse|NetBeans for Remote System Development in Solaris.

**What I exactly want is:** Use these IDE to Build,Debug and CheckIn purpose using Solaris C/C++
compiler and dbx debugger. I want to create the file in solaris from IDE compile and debug in IDE finaly checkIn using IDE.

**What I have achieved(only in NetBeans):** I am able to connect to the Solaris system using ssh.(Its like using Putty)

But not able to achieve all the GUI capability of IDE, By setting the Solaris compiler and Debugging capability.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Remote System Explorer` plugin using which i have been connecting to my linux shells through ssh. Works like a charm .

This link might prove helpful.
[How To: Browse remote files in Eclipse IDE](http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/).

Comment: Also ,super user would be a better place to ask such questions.

Comment: @Mlkhail: I am able to connect using ssh. But I want full utilization of IDE

Comment: I am saying , if you can connect using SSH , the plugin i specified helps u in doing so through the ide. For me , i have a left panel which shows me all the files in my linux directory. I open them like i would any local file. Edit , and save them . SSH is more like a protocol if that is what confused you. Did that clear things up?

Comment: @user43*, i am not sure of using advanced features like eclipse debugger and the likes through RSE .

Comment: @Mlkhail: Thanks for the reply.                                                   What I want is using all capability of IDE, Like create, toggle, commenting, formating, syntax check, keyword highlite etc. I am only able to use solaris vi and vim to edit and not getting any left panel. Do I have to use any specific version..!

Comment: ok. RSE plugin is for eclipse . I run eclipse on my windows machine , and access my linux code.

Comment: You can have commenting , formatting ,syntax checking ,keyword highlighting in Eclipse . All of them works for me . But autocompletion or other features that mite need access to files might not work properly .

Comment: This answer does not answer - how he can compile in Eclipse. Only edit remote files. Which is good, and enough for me. I just login with a separate shell and type "make". But he wanted something more.

Comment: You don't need a separate shell i guess. RSE has an inbuilt shell console too. Just saw that in the link i pasted :D